# Mechanism for formation of Quinol from a Phenolic Ether

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons

[image]

What's the mechanism for formation of Quinol from the given phenolic substrate? The reaction seems to be an acid catalysed hydrolysis, but I'm not able to reach the final product. I guess the first step should be addition of water to the nucleophilic π bond, but what after that?

Comment: The other product is acetaldehyde. So where is the double bond protonated?

Comment: Couldn't get to it yet. Could you please post the mechanism as an answer? Would be great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a mechanism for this enol ether hydrolysis.

[image]